# Execution of C# Lambda expressions based on async annotations

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to find an elegant implementation of the Execute(..) method below that takes in a lambda expression. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? It seems like I should be able to because the compiler will allow me to pass such a lambda expression (in the form of an Action).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This should execute SomeOperation() synchronously
        Execute(() => SomeOperation());

        // This should begin execution of SomeOperationAsync(), but not wait (fire and forget)
        Execute(() => SomeOperationAsync());

        // This should await the execution of SomeOperationAsync() (execute synchronously)
        Execute(async () => await SomeOperationAsync());
    }
```

How would you implement the Execute method above given these specifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* check whether the method underlying the delegate you've been passed is annotated with the [`AsyncStateMachineAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asyncstatemachineattribute.aspx) - but to be honest, I wouldn't. It's just asking for trouble, using an implementation detail like that.

Instead, I'd have a separate overload of `ExecuteAsyncDelegate` which took a `Func<Task>` instead of just `Action`. You need to be careful about what you do within that, of course - you quite possibly *don't* want to just block the executing thread. You may want to consider making *this* an async method as well. (It's not clear what your `Execute` method is meant to do other than just call the delegate - presumably it's adding value somewhere.)

For example, suppose you were actually doing this for timing purposes. You might have:

```
static async Task<TimeSpan> BenchmarkAsync(Func<Task> func)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await func();
    sw.Stop();
    return sw.Elapsed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'd appreciate knowing how I'd achieve what is outlined in the question using AsyncStateMachineAttribute. In this particular case I'm trying to avoid a separate overload ... it's an edge case.

Comment: @CraigSmitham: Well you can use the `Delegate.Method` property to get a `MethodInfo`, and then use `method.IsDefined(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute), false)` to check for its presence. It's not foolproof though - there's nothing to stop someone applying the attribute themselves.

Comment: Once I check for it, how would I treat it as a Func<Task> in order to execute it? I cannot seem to extract a Func<Task> from a void async lambda.

Comment: @CraigSmitham: If it's void, then you're in trouble. You'd need to change the task scheduler context to one which you control yourself, which is relatively painful - and then you'd need to handle differing requirements for the method. Fundamentally this is not going to be a pleasant experience, so I'd try to avoid doing this as far as you possibly can.

Comment: Thank you Jon, pain avoided.